# Are the identities $\{(xy)^p = x^p y^p : p \mbox{ is prime}\}$ logically independent?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

For each positive integer $n$, let $\eta_n$ denote the following identity in the language of monoids.

$$(xy)^n = x^n y^n$$

For example, $\eta_2$ is the identity $xyxy = xxyy.$

> **Question.** Is it true that for any subset $Q$ of the prime numbers $\{2,3,5,\ldots\}$, there exists a monoid $M$ such that for all prime numbers $p,$ $M$ satisfies $\eta_p$ iff $p \in Q$? In other words, is $\{\eta_2,\eta_3,\eta_5,\ldots\}$ a logically independent set of sentences? (In the presence of the monoid axioms).

For example (and I may be overlooking something obvious here), but I do not think that $(xy)^5 = x^5 y^5$ follows from just $(xy)^2=x^2 y^2$ and $(xy)^3 = x^3y^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the monoid $M$ given by the presentation $\langle x,y : \{(xy)^p = x^p y^p\}_{p \in Q} \rangle$. In order to show that $(xy)^q \neq x^q y^q$ in $M$ for $q \notin Q$, we use that two words $w,w'$ in $x,y$ become equal in $M$ if and only if $(w,w')$ lies in the equivalence relation generated by the following relation: There are words $a,b$ and $p \in Q$ such that $w=a (xy)^p b$, $w'=a x^p y^p b$. The good thing is that (in contrast to groups) no cancellation occurs. Thus, it becomes a "combinatorial" exercise to show that $(xy)^q$ and $x^q y^q$ are not equal in $M$. If they were, we would have to replace $(xy)^p$ by $x^p y^p$ somewhere in $(xy)^q$, which only works when $p \leq q$. We end up with $(xy)^i x^p y^p (xy)^{q-p-i}$. We can never reach $x^q$ or $y^q$ this way. Of course one really has to prove this, by induction perhaps. Please tell me if this makes any difficulties.

Comment: You can probably make this work, but it seems like it becomes complicated _very_ quickly especially when you have multiple indices in the set $Q$.

Comment: Note that the corresponding question for groups has a negative answer. Indeed, it is shown in [F. W. Barnes and Walter Stromquist, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 81, No. 4 (Apr., 1974), p. 410](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319020) that if a group satisfies the identities $x^ay^a = (xy)^a$ and $x^by^b = (xy)^b$ where the gcd of $a^2 - a$ and $b^2 -b$ is $2$, then the group is commutative. But of course groups are much more restricted than monoids!